# Add meta tags when block exist on page and its cached

Tags: 7, meta-tags

I have block with social sharing buttons. Need add 'og' and 'twitter' meta tags on page where block exists. I know that can add it throw `drupal_add_html_head()` inside block content render, but if block is cached meta tags not appear.
How do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of adding php code in the block you could add the code in a preprocess function for the block.

```
/**
 * Implements template_preprocess_block().
 */
function MYTHEME_preprocess_block(&$variables) {
  if ($variables['block']->bid == 'MYBLOCKID') {
    $og_title = array(
      '#tag' => 'meta',
      '#attributes' => array(
        'property' => 'og:title', 
        'content' => "My example title",
      ),
    );
    drupal_add_html_head($og_title, 'MYMODULE_og_title');
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! It works :) But, better use delta param.

Comment: @FriOne could you update my answer or post the suggested change as a comment so I can update?

Comment: I edited your answer. Also one question, I thought that preprocess is not called too when cached,  why drupal not cache after preprocess?